# Suppress extra messages on ansible assert when the assertion passed as ok?

Tags: ansible

Any time an assertion in ansible is passed ok I get a verbose output like this.

```
ok: [v-sax-769-e-a.develop.ebiz.grp] => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}
```

Is it possible to suppress this (only for successful) assertions ? The fist line starting with ok... would be enough.

I have seen old mails about this and asking for this feature, but in the documentation from ansible I could not find a flag or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue on that: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27124

In current Ansible version (2.4.1) `assert` is always in `verbose` mode.

Comment: Thanks, I am using 2.4.1 and so I am, kind of, out of luck :-(

Comment: You can copy `assert.py` into your local `action_plugins` directory, comment out always verbose setting and be happy :)

Answer (score 2):

To save everyone some time reading through the issue: since 2.8, you can add `quiet: yes` to the call to reduce verbosity, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/assert_module.html